# Print Nested Dictionary in Table Format

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested

I am trying to print my nested dictionary in a table format. But have not been able to do so. The table is a list of student names and student grades. I would like it to be in a "Report Card" type format that is easy to read. The for loop I am using prints out the results. But it is one column list form.

This is my current dictionary I have setup.

```
student = {
    "student1": {
        "Name": "Eddy",
        "Grade": 1,
        "Math": 78,
        "English": 65,
        "Physics": 89,
        "Chemistry": 80
    },
    "student2": {
        "Name": "Jim",
        "Grade": 2,
        "Math": 89,
        "English": 65,
        "Physics": 87,
        "Chemistry": 76

    },
    "student3": {
        "Name": "Jane",
        "Grade": 3,
        "Math": 87,
        "English": 97,
        "Physics": 75,
        "Chemistry": 64

    },
}
```

This is the for loop I am currently using.

```
for i in student:
    for j in student[i]:
        print(j + " : " + str(student[i][j]))
    print("===========")
```

I would like to print out in a table format.

```
Name Grade Math English Physics Chemistry
Eddy   1    78      65     89        80
Jim    2    89      65     87        76
Jane   3    87      97     75        64
```

I have tried to use the `format()` function but could not make it work with the nested dictionary.

I also tried using `pandas` and converting to a `pd.DataFrame`, but could not make it work.

Comment: it seen you should learn about `string formatting` in python - see page [pyFormat.info](https://pyformat.info/)

Comment: `print()` automatically add new line - so you may need `print(..., end="")` to print in one line.

Answer (score 5):

First: `print()` as default add `new line` at the end so if you want to display in one line then you have to use `print(..., end="")`

---

I think you should learn `string formatting` - see page [pyFormat.info](https://pyformat.info/). This way you can better control elements in row then using spaces or `\t`.

It needs to work with all elements at once instead of using internal `for`-loop but this gives better control and needs simpler code.

```
for stud, val in student.items():
    print("{:4} {:^5} {:^4} {:^7} {:^7} {:^9}".format(val["Name"], val["Grade"], val["Math"], val["English"], val["Physics"], val["Chemistry"]))
```

I use `items()` to get all values for one studen and later use `val["Name"]`, `val["Grade"}`, etc. so I'm sure I put values in correct order.

I use `{}` to define where to put element in string, and using `{:^5}` I define that it should use field which has 5 chars (it will add spaces if text is shorter) and `^` means it should center value in this field.

```
Name Grade Math English Physics Chemistry
Eddy   1    78    65      89       80    
Jim    2    89    65      87       76    
Jane   3    87    97      75       64
```

In `string formatting` you can use `{}` with any other text to decoreate table. For example you can put `|` between fields to create

```
+------+-------+------+---------+---------+-----------+
| Name | Grade | Math | English | Physics | Chemistry |
+------+-------+------+---------+---------+-----------+
| Eddy |   1   |  78  |   65    |   89    |    80     |
| Jim  |   2   |  89  |   65    |   87    |    76     |
| Jane |   3   |  87  |   97    |   75    |    64     |
+------+-------+------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

---

```
student = {
    "student1": {
        "Name": "Eddy",
        "Grade": 1,
        "Math": 78,
        "English": 65,
        "Physics": 89,
        "Chemistry": 80
    },
    "student2": {
        "Name": "Jim",
        "Grade": 2,
        "Math": 89,
        "English": 65,
        "Physics": 87,
        "Chemistry": 76

    },
    "student3": {
        "Name": "Jane",
        "Grade": 3,
        "Math": 87,
        "English": 97,
        "Physics": 75,
        "Chemistry": 64

    },
}

print('Name Grade Math English Physics Chemistry')

for stud, val in student.items():
    print("{:4} {:^5} {:^4} {:^7} {:^7} {:^9}".format(val["Name"], val["Grade"], val["Math"], val["English"], val["Physics"], val["Chemistry"]))

print('+------+-------+------+---------+---------+-----------+')
print('| Name | Grade | Math | English | Physics | Chemistry |')
print('+------+-------+------+---------+---------+-----------+')

for stud, val in student.items():
    print("| {:4} | {:^5} | {:^4} | {:^7} | {:^7} | {:^9} |".format(val["Name"], val["Grade"], val["Math"], val["English"], val["Physics"], val["Chemistry"]))

print('+------+-------+------+---------+---------+-----------+')
```

---

BTW: to make it more universal you could use list `'Name', 'Grade', 'Math', 'English', 'Physics', 'Chemistry']` to decide which values display. You could also need code which calculate width for columns but it would be more complex code.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) solution, as you mentioned unsuccessfully trying pandas. You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `orient=index`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(student, orient='index').reset_index(drop=True)
```

You get

```
    Name    Grade   Math    English Physics Chemistry
0   Eddy    1       78      65      89      80
1   Jim     2       89      65      87      76
2   Jane    3       87      97      75      64
```

### For a `markdown` table

- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html)

```
print(df.to_markdown(index=False))

| Name   |   Grade |   Math |   English |   Physics |   Chemistry |
|:-------|--------:|-------:|----------:|----------:|------------:|
| Eddy   |       1 |     78 |        65 |        89 |          80 |
| Jim    |       2 |     89 |        65 |        87 |          76 |
| Jane   |       3 |     87 |        97 |        75 |          64 |
```

- The benefit of pandas over other implementations, is the data is now in a format for easy analysis and plotting.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.plot.barh(x='Name', y=['Math', 'English', 'Physics', 'Chemistry'], figsize=(6, 8))
plt.xlabel('Score')
plt.legend(title='Subject', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

just happened to write one yesterday. sharing it.

```py
student = {
    "student1": {
        "Name": "Eddy",
        "Grade": 1,
        "Math": 78,
        "English": 65,
        "Physics": 89,
        "Chemistry": 80
    },
    "student2": {
        "Name": "Jim",
        "Grade": 2,
        "Math": 89,
        "English": 65,
        "Physics": 87,
        "Chemistry": 76

    },
    "student3": {
        "Name": "Jane",
        "Grade": 3,
        "Math": 87,
        "English": 97,
        "Physics": 75,
        "Chemistry": 64

    },
}

columns = list(student.values())[0].keys()
width = [len(col) for col in columns ]
print(" ".join(columns))
col_format = []
for w in width:
    if len(col_format) == 0:
        col_format.append("%s")
    else:
        col_format.append("%" + str(w) + "d")
str_col_format = " ".join(col_format)

for vals in student.values():
    values = list(vals.values())
    values[0] = f"{values[0].ljust(width[0])}"
    print(str_col_format % tuple(values))
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most elegant way, but it does work.

```py
print('\t'.join(['Name', 'Grade', 'Math', 'English', 'Physics', 'Chemistry']))
for stud in student:
    for topic in student[stud]:
        print(student[stud][topic], end='\t')
    print()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_keys(my_dict):
    keys = list(my_dict.keys())
    keys = my_dict[keys[0]].keys()
    keys = list(keys)
    return keys

# get headers
keys = get_keys(students)

# print header
for key in keys:
    print("%10s " %key, end="")
print("\n")

# print body
for values in students.values():
    for key in keys:
        print("%10s "%str(values[key]), end="")
    print("\n")
```

(this will not necessarily print Name as the first column though)

Comment: Thanks I will test the above solutions out.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in `.values()` of the `dict` to `pandas.DataFrame`

```py
import pandas as pd

student = ...

df = pd.DataFrame(student.values())
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```